# Meaning of やる stem in this sentence

Tags: meaning

The sentence in question is the following.

> その　しゅくだいを　**やりおわったら**、　ちょっと　こちらを　てつだって　くれませんか。

I can't figure out what やり is supposed to mean here since there is no kanji present in the sentence. I'm guessing the first part of the sentence means *If you're done with that homework*, but none of the やる verbs in the dictionary have a meaning close to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as meaning,

「やる」＝「する」＝「行{おこな}う」 = "***to do***"

「やりおわったら」＝「しおわったら」 = "***when you are done with ~~"***

「やる」, in this context, means "to do".  It is a little more informal than 「する」 and much more informal than 「行う」.　It is an extremely common meaning of 「やる」, which has many meanings.

See definition #6 here in [デジタル大辞泉{だいじせん}](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%81%A3%E3%82%8B-649916#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by the word "stem" here, but certainly the origin goes way back to even around **[from 10th to 14th century.](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E9%81%A3%E3%82%8B)**. The original kanji form varies, for example 遣(や）る 遣（＝meaning, send, summon, give, ) as a transitive verb, from above **[徒然草](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsurezuregusa)** ( English Wiki ),

The Japanese original

> 明日（あす）その値（あたひ）をやりて牛を取らんといふ

The Japanese modern version

> （牛を買う人は）明日その代金を払って牛を受け取ろうという。

English Tranlslation

> (The person who buy the cow) says he will pay ( = give ) the money tomorrow and receive the cow.

or a subsidiary verb やる such as from **[源氏物語](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tale_of_Genji)**　( English ) to denote, do, finish.

The Japanese original

> 言ひもやらず、むせかへり給（たま）ふほどに

The modern Japanese

> （母君は悲しみのために）最後まで言うこともできず、むせび泣きなさっているうちに。

The English translation

> (The mother, due to her deep grief) was not able to finish to say to the last, crying and choking with..

The conjugative form is ( basically ) **[ラ行五段活用](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/223431/m0u/)**。

So the conjugation form is

> 語幹(stem) や（or遣）
>
> 未然形(Imperfective) ら
>
> 連用形(Conjunctive) り/っ
>
> 終止形(Predicative) る
>
> 連体形(Attributive) る
>
> 仮定形(Conditional) れ
>
> 命令形(Imperative)  れ

So among out of various meanings your speech **やりおわったら**

will denote using, "to do" or "have finished XXX",

> when ( you ) have done XXX

### The translation of your whole sentence

> その　しゅくだいを　やりおわったら、　ちょっと　こちらを　てつだって　くれませんか
>
> After you have finished the ( your ) homework, could you help me ( mine ) a little bit too?

Have a nice day.

Comment: Some books for learners call the 連用形 form of a verb "the stem", although I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: Then I am sorry I am not also.........